# Sometimes SQL Server trigger is not firing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a trigger on my `recharge` table. It updates the balance of `onaccountregistry` table.

But sometimes when inserting rows into my `recharge` table it is not firing the trigger. Then values are mismatch. This `recharge` table insert rows every time.

I created the trigger as follows. This is not a replicated table. I'm using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise edition.

Please help me solve this matter

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[RechargeRefund] 
   ON [dbo].[ISRecharge]  
   FOR INSERT  
AS
   declare @tin char(9) 
   declare @depocd char(1) 
   declare @oldvalue money
   declare @newvalue money
begin
    select @tin = inserted.tin_subtin from inserted
    select @depocd = inserted.updatetype from inserted
    select @newvalue = inserted.DepositAmt from inserted
    select @oldvalue = Totdeposit from ISOnAcctRegistry where tin_subtin = @tin
end

if @depocd ='1'
begin
  update ISOnAcctRegistry
  set Totdeposit = @oldvalue + @newvalue
  where tin_subtin = @tin
end 

if @depocd ='2'
begin
  update ISOnAcctRegistry
  set Totdeposit = @oldvalue - @newvalue
  where tin_subtin = @tin
end
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

As @marc points out, writing assuming a single row in `inserted` is bad - it can even be possible for your 3 selects from `inserted` to assign values to your 3 variables from 3 different (arbitrary) rows from `inserted`.

What you probably want is:

```
update i1
set Totdeposit = Totdesposit + t2.Total
from ISOnAcctRegistry i1
        inner join
     (select
         tin_subtin,
         SUM(CASE updatetype
              WHEN 1 THEN DepositAmt
              WHEN 2 THEN -DepositAmt
         ELSE 0 END) as Total
      from inserted
      group by tin_subtin) t2
        on
            i1.tin_subtin = t2.tin_subtin
```

But you might be able to replace this work (and this column in `ISOnAcctRegistry`) with an indexed view built on `ISRecharge` - with some limitations, you *can* build a view that automatically performs a `SUM` across the rows in `ISRecharge`, and SQL Server would take responsibility for maintaining the value in the background for you.

Obviously, at present, your trigger doesn't account for any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` activity on `ISRecharge`. An indexed view would.

Answer (score 2):

Well, of course it won't work - you're assuming that the trigger fires **once per row inserted**.

But that's **NOT** the case.

The trigger fires **once per `INSERT` batch**, and the pseudo-table `Inserted` might contain **multiple rows**!

If you did get an `INSERT` with more than one row - which row did your statements here select ?

```
select @tin = inserted.tin_subtin from inserted
select @depocd = inserted.updatetype from inserted
select @newvalue = inserted.DepositAmt from inserted
select @oldvalue = Totdeposit from ISOnAcctRegistry where tin_subtin = @tin
```

You need to rewrite your trigger so that it will handle **multiple rows** in `Inserted` - then it'll work every time.

Comment: How can I handle multiple row inserted please change my triger dear.please help me to do this

Comment: @user1811342 - If you'd care to look at my answer, provided yesterday, it shows how the trigger ought to be written.